# Dynamically update html file based on form input(s)

Tags: html, forms

I use a site called finviz.com which provides stock charts.  I like to view the charts along different timeframes, one on top of the other. I have been using excel to do this. E.g. if i enter "aapl" in cell A1, I use a simple concatenate formula in excel to put together the hyperlinks I need as follows:

```
<img src = 'http://elite.finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=aapl&ty=c&ta=st_c,sch_100,sma2_50,sma2_20,sma2_100,stofu_b_5_3_3&p=d&s=l'><br>
<img src = 'http://elite.finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=aapl&ty=c&ta=0&p=i15&s=l'><br>
<img src = 'http://elite.finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=aapl&ty=c&ta=0&p=i3&s=l'>[/code]
```

however this is pretty slow going. for each different ticker, i need to copy/paste the excel text into an html file on my desktop and refresh my chrome browser. i would prefer to have an input field in my html code that lets me enter a ticker symbol which then dynamically updates the html code for a different stock.

Can anybody suggest how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't want to use JQuery here is a plain JavaScript version of intracept's very nice code.

```
<input type="text" id="tickerCode" /><input type="button" id="setTicker" value="Set Ticker" />

<img id="ticker1" src = 'http://elite.finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=aapl&ty=c&ta=st_c,sch_100,sma2_50,sma2_20,sma2_100,stofu_b_5_3_3&p=d&s=l'><br>
<img id="ticker2" src = 'http://elite.finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=aapl&ty=c&ta=0&p=i15&s=l'><br>
<img id="ticker3" src = 'http://elite.finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=aapl&ty=c&ta=0&p=i3&s=l'>
<script>
document.getElementById('setTicker').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var symbol = document.getElementById('tickerCode').value;
  document.getElementById('ticker1').src = 'http://elite.finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=' + symbol + '&ty=c&ta=st_c,sch_100,sma2_50,sma2_20,sma2_100,stofu_b_5_3_3&p=d&s=l';
  document.getElementById('ticker2').src = 'http://elite.finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=' + symbol + '&ty=c&ta=0&p=i15&s=l';
  document.getElementById('ticker3').src = 'http://elite.finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=' + symbol + '&ty=c&ta=0&p=i3&s=l';
});
</script>
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you so much to both of you.

One small request - can you tell me what I would add to the code to make pressing the enter key be the equivalent of clicking the button? And also, after the enter button is pressed, is there a way to delete the ticker that may have been entered in the field box and put the focus back there? I would like to type: googl, enter, aapl, enter, nflx, enter, msft, enter, etc. so i can quickly skim through different charts without having to do too much clicking or typing.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is to set up your input box and button, then use jQuery to update the image source.

Add a new input box and button to your HTML and give ids to your images:

```
<input type="text" id="tickerCode" /><input type="button" id="setTicker" value="Set Ticker" />

<img id="ticker1" src = 'http://elite.finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=aapl&ty=c&ta=st_c,sch_100,sma2_50,sma2_20,sma2_100,stofu_b_5_3_3&p=d&s=l'><br>
<img id="ticker2" src = 'http://elite.finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=aapl&ty=c&ta=0&p=i15&s=l'><br>
<img id="ticker3" src = 'http://elite.finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=aapl&ty=c&ta=0&p=i3&s=l'>
```

Now on your new button click:

```
$('#setTicker').click(function () {
    $('#ticker1').attr("src", 'http://elite.finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=' + $('#tickerCode').val() + '&ty=c&ta=st_c,sch_100,sma2_50,sma2_20,sma2_100,stofu_b_5_3_3&p=d&s=l');
    $('#ticker2').attr("src", 'http://elite.finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=' + $('#tickerCode').val() + '&ty=c&ta=0&p=i15&s=l');
    $('#ticker3').attr("src", 'http://elite.finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=' + $('#tickerCode').val() + '&ty=c&ta=0&p=i3&s=l');

});
```